# throw WebDriverException when using selenium webdriver to upload file

Tags: python, selenium, upload, webdriver

I want to upload file using the following python code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("fileFieldName-file").send_keys("D:\\manual.pdf")
```

the code works fine in Firefox, but it fails in IE and Chrome. The exception is as follows:

`WebDriverException: Message: '{ "status" : 404, "sessionId" : "<no session>", "value" : "Command not found: POST /session/e56793e2-79f9-4bb9-820e-91090ccee083/file" }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer by myself.
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3736
It is a bug of selenium.The solution as follows:
1. find the file "webelement.py" in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium-2.21.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote
2. find the function "_upload" in "webelement.py"
3.change the code of function "_upload", add a condtion in the exception handing part.

```
def _upload(self, filename):
    fp = StringIO()
    zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zipped.write(filename)
    zipped.close()
    try:
        return self._execute(Command.UPLOAD_FILE, 
                        {'file': base64.encodestring(fp.getvalue())})['value']
    except WebDriverException as e:
        if "Unrecognized command: POST" in e.__str__():
            return filename
        elif "Command not found: POST" in e.__str__():
            return filename
        else:
            raise e
```

**strong text**